# Redux-Form reducer plugin not causing component to rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have been trying to follow the example [here](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/).

I have code containing the following:

```
export default reduxForm({form: 'AlertTriggerSettingsForm'})(AlertTriggerSettingsFormContainer)
```

...

```
export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer.plugin({ AlertTriggerSettingsForm: alertTriggerSettings })
})
```

...

```
const alertTriggerSettings = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_VARIABLE_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentVariable: action.variable,
        values: {
          currentHighValue: '55',
          currentLowValue: '66'
        }
      }
  }
}
```

...

```
<Field name='currentLowValue'
      label='Low Set Point:'
      component={HighLowInputField} />
```

...

```
const HighLowInputField = ({ label, input: { value, onChange }, meta: { error } }) => (
  <div className='form-group'>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input
      onChange={onChange}
      className='form-control'
      type='number' />
  </div>
)
```

When the reducer is called, in Redux dev tools I can see that the state is successfully updated, however the component fails to rerender and no @@redux-form/CHANGE event is dispatched.  When I manually enter input into the field, the event is dispatched and the state and component are updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to understand more here.

Are you using `redux` here?

If so, is it all connected - like this

```
let myForm = reduxForm({form: 'AlertTriggerSettingsForm'})(AlertTriggerSettingsFormContainer)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // Your state here
})

let connectedPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(myForm);

export { connectedPage as MyComponent };
```